# Slick codeGenerator does not fill foreignKey names causing assertion failed: duplicate foreign key names detected

Tags: scala, foreign-keys, slick

```
val included = Seq("File", "Project", "FileContent")
val model = db.withSession { implicit session =>        
    val tables = SQLiteDriver.getTables.list.filter(t => included.contains(t.name.name))
    createModel(tables, SQLiteDriver)
  }
model.assertConsistency;
```

running the code above causes

```
java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: duplicate foreign key names detected
    at scala.Predef$.assert(Predef.scala:179)
    at scala.slick.model.Model$$anonfun$assertConsistency$3.apply(Model.scala:94)
    at scala.slick.model.Model$$anonfun$assertConsistency$3.apply(Model.scala:84)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at scala.slick.model.Model.assertConsistency(Model.scala:84)
    ...
```

following code prints all three keys incorrectly with ForeignKey.name=None

```
println(model.tables.foreach(t => println(t.foreignKeys)));

ArrayBuffer(
ForeignKey(None,QualifiedName(File,None,None),List(Column(parent,QualifiedName(File,None,None),Int,true,Set())),QualifiedName(File,None,None),List(Column(id,QualifiedName(File,None,None),Int,false,Set(PrimaryKey))),NoAction,NoAction), 
       ForeignKey(None,QualifiedName(File,None,None),List(Column(content,QualifiedName(File,None,None),String,true,Set())),QualifiedName(FileContent,None,None),List(Column(hash,QualifiedName(FileContent,None,None),String,false,Set(PrimaryKey))),NoAction,NoAction), 
       ForeignKey(None,QualifiedName(File,None,None),List(Column(project,QualifiedName(File,None,None),Int,false,Set())),QualifiedName(Project,None,None),List(Column(id,QualifiedName(Project,None,None),Int,false,Set(PrimaryKey))),NoAction,NoAction)
    )
```

but the this code prints key names correctly

```
db.withSession { implicit session =>    
    SQLiteDriver.getTables.list.filter(t => included.contains(t.name.name)).foreach(t => println(t.getExportedKeys.list))    
  }

List(MForeignKey(MQName(Project),id,MQName(File),project,1,NoAction,NoAction,Some(),Some(),5))
List(MForeignKey(MQName(FileContent),hash,MQName(File),content,1,NoAction,NoAction,Some(),Some(),5))
List(MForeignKey(MQName(File),id,MQName(File),parent,1,NoAction,NoAction,Some(),Some(),5))
```

is there any way to force slick to fill key names correctly, or how can be those names altered without having to recreate the whole model by hand with different key name values ?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the extensive explanation by the way! Helped tracking it down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the jdbc driver of your DMBS does not provide foreign key names or they were all empty. So the model is actually correct, but the consistency checker has a bug. You can simply disable it:

```
val model = new scala.slick.model.Model( createModel(tables, SQLiteDriver).tables ){
  override def assertConsistency = () // disable broken consistency check
}
```

Which DMBS are you using?

This will be fixed in 2.0.2: https://github.com/slick/slick/pull/747

Comment: I am using sqlite. Versions slick "2.0.1", sqlite-jdbc 3.7.2

Comment: But the solution you wrote works fine! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Updated answer with pull request